# Cross product of vectors separated by $\pi$ rad

Tags: vectors

for two vectors A & B separated by $\pi$ rad, what is the direction of $\vec A \times \vec B$?

Generally we take the smaller angle between them but here there is a confusion since both clockwise & anti-clockwise sense give equal angle.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\vec A\times\vec B|=|\vec A||\vec B|\sin\theta$$
$$\theta=\pi$$
$$|\vec A\times\vec B|=|\vec A||\vec B|(0)=0$$

Thus, the resultant is a zero vector and taking any direction is the same.

Comment: would the sense of the zero vector be out of the plane containing A & B or into the plane?

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense.  At pi radians, A × B = B × A = zero (both magnitude, or equivalently, area of a parallelogram, AND direction).  The directions obtained by the right-hand rule (turning A into B or B into A) exactly cancel each other out.

And also a very helpful question I was about to post myself.

Comment: Welcome to math.se, however answers should not be used for comments.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-product is zero in that situation. Remember that the magnitude of the cross-product is given by the area of the parallelogram spanned by the two vectors. This area is zero for parallel vectors.

Comment: That statement is true, but the OP probably does not understand why. Can you expand on that?

Comment: does zero vector indicates any direction? Or does it presume any possible direction sense?

Comment: @katipra Indeed, the zero vector is special in that it has undefined (or arbitrary) direction.

Comment: The doubt was regarding the orientation of the zero vector such that it is always perpendicular to the plane containing A & B . Now, I think I get the answer. Here is what I understand : let the zero vector points in any arbitrary direction except lets say A. Then we can construct a plane perpendicular to the zero vector containing A, hence also containing B. Please clarify if wrong & on the possibility that the direction of zero vector coinciding with both A & B.

Comment: @katipra It's not meaningful to say that the zero vector points in an arbitrary direction except the one $A$ has. We should agree that either that the zero vector does not point anywhere or else that it points everywhere. In any case, this is a matter of convention and bears no mathematical significance.